# set/listen to Animation listener for single animation used by multiple views

Tags: java, android, animation

I am using slide up animation for two different views ie 1) Imageview 2) Textview.
The problem is i am using setAnimationListener for slideUpAnim, to detect its animation end. I am stuck in knowing which view's slideUpAnim ended inside "onAnimationEnd()" method. I am posting necessary code.

in SplashActivity.java

```
final Animation zoomOutAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_in);
logo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
logo.startAnimation(zoomOutAnim);
final Animation slideUpAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.bottom_up);

zoomOutAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            logo.startAnimation(slideUpAnim);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
});

slideUpAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // this is where i am facing loop problem, once logo finishes with slide up anim, 
            //i am starting same slide up animation for 'info' textview, now since animation is same 
            //i am unable to distinguish slideup anim end for which view.
            info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            info.startAnimation(slideUpAnim);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

once "info" textview also finishes with slideup anim, i want to open MainActivity in 'onAnimationEnd()" of slideUpAnim animation listener.

Please help me or suggest me.

Comment: create a class implementing `Animation.AnimationListener` and pass your View when calling its constructor

Comment: since i am using same animation for both views but not starting animation simultaneously, i am setting animationListener for slideUpAnim, at first logo finishes with slideUpAnim and in "onAnimationEnd()" i am starting same slideUp animation for "info", but this time since code of animationListener is already implemented for slideUpAnim, i want to launch next activity in its onAnimationEnd method but have to check which view finished slideUpAnim so i can decide which code to run using if else.